# connman network manager in enlightenment

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, connman

I am able to install Enlightenment on Ubuntu 14.04 as well as Connman network manager but unable to start EConnman in Enligntenment. It returns with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/econnman-bin", line 45, in <module>
import elementary as elm
ImportError: No module named elementary
```

Comment: Tried, Unable to find such package.

Comment: Try to install it from the source code ----> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-elementary/1.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue while compiling on 14.04.

The issue is the prefix and the path. The default prefix for the econnman packages is '/usr/local' along with the Enlightenment and EFL packages, etc. If you don't want to remove the packages and recompile them with the prefix = /usr (recommended), you can symlink the libraries from /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib.

I would say to bite the bullet and clean the packages and reinstall using the correct prefix. This helps with a lot of other issues that arise from the incorrect path being used for the installation, such as the location of the .desktop file for Enlightenment, etc.

If you make the symlinks instead, econnman-bin will startup just fine. To know exactly what libraries it's looking for to make the symlinks without having to debug too much, run an strace and note the files that can't be found/opened.

Comment: Kindly Edit your Answer